# How to checked my checkbox according to the data from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CAT A or CAT C">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcata" OnCheckedChanged="chkcata_CheckedChanged" OnDataBinding="chkcata_DataBinding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cat_a") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("cat_a").ToString().Equals("1")%>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Port to Trikon">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkport" Style="text-align: center" OnCheckedChanged="chkport_CheckedChanged" OnDataBinding="chkport_DataBinding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Port_Trikon") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="White Pages Listing? Y/N">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkwhilepages" Style="text-align: center" OnCheckedChanged="chkwhilepages_CheckedChanged" OnDataBinding="chkwhilepages_DataBinding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("while_pages") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

the image u can see which is my gridview, in which the checkbox are given. Now on update time when i execute my filladd() function the checkbox are not checked even they are true so please help it out..!!

```
private void filladd(int p)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = b.get_subpaf(p);//MJ SP CHANGE
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {        
        DataExtensionList.DataSource = dt;
        DataExtensionList.DataBind();
        ViewState["ExtensionId"] = dt.Rows.Count;
        ExtensionBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I see is that the 2 check boxes do not have their Checked property set. Instead they have their Text property Set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkport" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"Port_Trikon").ToString()!="0"?true:false %>' />
```

Make sure that Database is either BIT datatype or just return 1, 0 string

Answer (score 0):

i got the above answer just replace this function with the old one which is asked in question

```
private void filladd(int p)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = b.get_subpaf(p);//MJ SP CHANGE
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        DataExtensionList.DataSource = dt;
        DataExtensionList.DataBind();
        foreach (GridViewRow it1 in DataExtensionList.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)it1.FindControl("chkcata");
            CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)it1.FindControl("chkport");
            CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox)it1.FindControl("chkwhilepages");
            if (chk.Text == "True")
            {
                chk.Checked = true;
            }
            if (chk1.Text == "True")
            {
                chk1.Checked = true;
            }
            if (chk2.Text == "True")
            {
                chk2.Checked = true;
            }
        }
     }
}
```